# MATLAB OOP global objects in functions seen as empty

Tags: matlab, function, oop, struct, global-variables

I am facing a strange behaviour in MATLAB when declaring an object variable as global. Where all global doubles I define seem to be recognizable by functions, it seems not possible to do the same with objects, or structs of objects that are defined from a class. This is what I have done.

Class definition:

```
classdef Class < handle

    properties
        property
    end

    methods
        function obj = Constructor(value)
            if nargin == 1 
                obj.property   = value;
            end
        end
    end

end
```

Construction of objects array:

```
% Define objects array as global variable to be accessible in functions    
global objectsArray variableA

% define value of variable A, to be accessible in functions
variableA = 123;

% Values to be assigned to objects' property field    
values = [1,2,3]; 

% initialise object array using constructor
if isempty(objectsArray) 
    objectsArray(3,1) = Constructor();
end

% define objects' property field
for k = 1:3  
    objectsArray(k) = Constructor( values(k) );
end
```

Now, I'd like a function to access both the objects array, and variable A, both defined above, and both declared as global variables. However, if I build a function as follows, only variable A is accessible, while the objects array is seen as an *empty variable*.

```
function varargout = doSomething (varargin)

    global objectsArray variableA

    aaa = variableA;
    bbb = objcetsArray(1).property; <--- code crashes here

end
```

The code crashes at executing the instruction defining `bbb`. Debug mode reveals that objectsArray is empty, and that variableA is equal to its value, 123. Ending debug mode, exiting therefore the function's execution, the objectsArray is defined as I'd expect, as a structure of 3 objects.

My question is, why does this happen? Why does it seem possible to recall global variables, but not if they are defined as objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I realised the problem was not the object itself, but the concept of global variable and how MATLAB works with it.

The same issue materializes when trying to make a struct global.

An answer to my question is explained in [this thread](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/237072) by the user Steven Lord:

> The problem here is not caused by global, at least not directly. When
>   you  define a variable to be global, it starts out as an empty
>   (0-by-0) double  array. So this line:
>
> global array_Structure
>
> sets array_Structure to be a global array containing [].
>
> Now when you try to assign a struct array (data_Struct) into an
>   element of  the array_Structure double variable, since the variable
>   has to be all one  type, MATLAB has to convert one of the variables
>   into the other's type. In  this case, since you're trying to put the
>   struct into the double array, it  tries to convert the struct into a
>   double array. For some pairs of the  built-in data types, MATLAB knows
>   how to convert between the two data types  implicitly (for instance,
>   double to single) -- but struct and double is not  one of those pairs
>   of types, so MATLAB says that converting a struct into a  double is
>   not possible. It doesn't know how to do it.